# Unedefined value, debugger, WHY?

Tags: c++, debugging, resources

Ok so firstly I'm not a cpp guru nor a big user of the debugger but...
At the begining of my program I have something like this

```
    unsigned long totSize;
    unsigned int partSize,lastPartSize;
    unsigned short nbRessources;
    const char* folder = "TYPE";

    getSizesRessource(folder, nbRessources, partSize, lastPartSize);
    totSize = (nbRessources*partSize)+lastPartSize;
```

I'm not gonna talk about this code, I don't think it really matter. 
The problem is this: the debugger shows strange value for folder or undefined value, same for totSize but I'm sure getSizesRessource works well and the other variables are right
So why the debugger doesn't show the righ value or undefined value even if I assign it clearly?
Even if i assigne "1" to totSize It still undefined in the debugger
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
    unsigned long totSize;
    unsigned int partSize,lastPartSize;
    unsigned short nbRessources;
```

Assuming the snippet of code is local to a function. The above just declares the variables with uninitialized values technically they hold **Indeterminate values**. As the name Indeteminate suggests these values can be literally anything.

If you are using the function `getSizesRessource` to populate these variables then your variables should be passed by reference to the function otherwise the function modifies copies of the variables being passed and the changes won't be reflected outside the functions.

Comment: @user2177904: I should be properly initialized. Unless you show a small compilable minimalistic code example it is difficult to speculate why you get other result.

Comment: I already give them as reference:
 void getSizesRessource(const char* folder , unsigned short &nbRess, unsigned int &partSize, unsigned int &lastPartSize)

except for folder but this one is a const and is initialized and the problem seems here. The debugger doesn't show folder values, nor totsize which is just the result of some math..